# Spurious rotation events while switching tasks in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app is crashing when you return to it after switching away from it using the 4-finger task-switch gesture on an iPad.

When the user does the 4-finger gesture to switch away from my app, I see `applicationWillResignActive:` then `applicationDidEnterBackground:` in my app delegate, then (assuming we're currently in portrait orientation) my top-level view controller gets `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` with a size that indicates landscape layout (even though the device has not rotated). This of course results in a lot of resizing and rearranging of views for the new orientation. Immediately after that I get `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` with a size that indicates portrait (the original orientation of the device). And again, I go through all my layout again for the new (actually, original) orientation.

What I'm finding is that if I wait for all of this to complete, I can switch in and out of my app all day. If, on the other hand, I switch back to my app while this needless work is going on, I get a crash deep in some iOS transition code.

At this point I'm trying to understand why I get these stray rotation events. If I can avoid getting those, I can avoid getting into whatever situation is causing the crash. They don't seem necessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. At first I thought I couldn't reproduce it, and then I realized that not only could I reproduce it but in fact my app on the App Store was full of crash reports because of it!

Comment: I have found another circumstance where this happens, when the user clicks the Home button while the app is in a multitasking situation. Once again, two `viewWillTransitionToSize` in quick succession while the app is in the background state.

Comment: I'm thinking the reason it's doing this is so that it can snapshot the app in both landscape and portrait so that it can show a thumbnail in its list of running apps. With the code in place to bypass orientation changes that happen in the background, exit your app in landscape, rotate to portrait, then double-click home to show the running apps. Your screen shot will be wrong. I think to truly fix this I need to figure out what's happening in my rotation/layout code that triggers the bug in iOS related to overlapping animations. In the meantime, I'm delaying layout until my app becomes active.

Comment: If that were the reason, why don’t we get these events every time the app is backgrounded, no matter how?   Like when you just click the Home button?

Comment: I don't know. The crash I experienced was because populating my main window requires processing data on background threads so it takes a little time. iOS does its snapshot while I am still in the middle of getting everything set up. The result is a crash somewhere in iOS. What I'm doing now is overlaying my main window with a static view when I go into the background and removing it when I become active again. When layoutSubviews sees this static view, it doesn't do layout for any subviews but that one (avoiding crash). The snapshot captures this static view. No other work-around required.

Comment: Clever! You should modify your answer to include that. Might want to show the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there isn't a way to prevent the rotation events from being reported to the app. I suspect that's an iOS bug. However, ignoring `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` when the application state is `UIApplicationStateBackground` and doing the same in the view's `layoutSubviews` (if present) allowed me to work around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason why it would be useful or correct to get `viewWillTransitionToSize` in the background, so just bounce out if you *are* in the background:

```
if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
    return
}
```

Still, this feels like a bug, and in my opinion you should report it to Apple.

Comment: To put it another way: if you implement `layoutSubviews`, whether it is called or not has nothing to do with whether you implement `viewWillTransitionToSize`. But that is _not what you asked about_.

Comment: Shall we remove our comments? It will be cleaner.

Comment: Just delete all your comments too, as I suggested. Your answer stands. Comments are ephemeral; we used them to debate how to proceed. Now the debate is over.